# Unexpected inability to run TOR-- said firefox crashed -- MAC OS 7.5.x

Tags: firefox, mac

TOR ran for a week.  Then crashed due to "Firefox crash"ing, which I do not have.  Says it's avail for Mac 7.0 or higher, and yet, now I cannot download or run either TOR or firefox, only safari.  Icons come with a circle and slash thru them.
 This sucks.